# checkbox image form with jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a checkbox form that has mouse over image and checked image function with jquery.

I successfully made each function but didn't work together.

here is my html form.

```
<label for="w_interest">
    <img src="/images/account/w_select.png_img"/ style='cursor:pointer;'>
    <input name="w_interest" type="checkbox" id="w_interest" style="display:none">
</label>
```

here is jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#w_interest').hover(
    function () {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '/images/account/w_select_hover.png');
    },
    function () {
        $('img', this).attr('src', '/images/account/w_select.png');
    }
  );

    $("#w_interest").change(function() {
       if(this.checked) {
           $(this).prev().attr("src", "/images/account/w_select_checked.png");
       } else {
           $(this).prev().attr("src", "/images/account/w_select.png");
       }
    });

});
```

1. when a user move their mouse pointer on the image, the image changes to mouse over image.
2. when he or she clicks the image, it changes to checked image. (of course, it checks the checkbox)

Can you help me to combine these two functions to make it happen?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? Can you provide a link or a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover event is set on an input field that is hidden, so it can't work.

```
<input name="w_interest" type="checkbox" id="w_interest" style="display:none">
```

So I think that you want the hover effect on the image? Give the image an id and work attach the event to the image.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/yB4rQ/

Comment: This one works fine! but the checked image doesn't stay after it checked

Comment: You have to do some programming of course like you wish how it works. You can remove the hover action once clicked, or you can make hover images of the checked and unchecked images. Than I would suggest to put them in variables or something. Once clicked, change the image variables. Any way, you have to put the logic in the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
if(this.checked)
```

write:

```
if ( $(this).is(':checked') )
```